# Need help on understanding a theorem on subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

An example in my textbook for Discrete Mathematics states, that,

Let A be a set, and B = {A, {A}}
Then A is a included in B, and so is {A} also an element of B. (Understood)
Also it states, {A} is a subset of B, and {{A}} also is a subset of B,
however it is not true that A is a subset of B.

I have some trouble understanding the theorem fully.
And here are the questions regarding to the example above:

1) Is element A in the set B, letter A or the set A?

2) Is {A} an unnamed set that contains element A (as in letter)?

3) How would you define {{A}}?

4) WHy is A not a subset of B? (I'd understand that A is not a subset of B, if the 3 previous questions are true)

Comment: $A$ will be a subset of $\{A,\{A\}\}$ if (and only if) $A$ happens to be the empty set ...

Comment: what if when set A = {A}

Comment: x @hs2345: There is no set $A$ in standard set theory that satisfies the condition $A=\{A\}$.

Comment: i mean when set A = {A} (letter A)? Is there a law that specifically prevents use of upper case letter for element in a set? or prohibits use of same alphabet as the name of set?

Comment: It is incredibly dangerous to have a symbol meaning multiple different things.  Perhaps it would be easier to call the *set* something like $\mathcal{A}$ while the element in the set is $A$.,  I.e. $\mathcal{A}=\{A\}$.

Comment: x @hs2345: The principle of not being needlessly confusing specifically says that if the same letter appears several times in a formula, it should mean the same thing each time (unless you have really good reason to let it stand for two different things _and_ notation to communicate when the meanings are different). If $A$ means some set on the left side of the $=$, then $A$ should mean the same set on the right side of the $=$. And since standard set theory has no set that has itself as an element, the same thing cannot simultaneously be described as $A$ and as $\{A\}$.

Comment: Thanks that helped clarifying some of the concept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. $B = \{A, \{A\}\}$.
   The elements of the set $B$ are $A$ and $\{A\}$.
   $A$ is a set in its own right, as well. You can visualize this pretty easily. Imagine $A$ is a deck of cards (or a set of cards). Then, $\{A\}$ would be the box the cards came in, with the cards inside. 
   $B$ would be a bigger box: it would contain the deck of cards, as well as the box containing the deck of cards.
2. $\{A\}$ is the set containing $A$. In our case, $A$ is a set. So, $\{A\}$ is the set containing the set $A$, or the set that has the set $A$ as an element.
3. $\{\{A\}\}$ would be the set containing the set containing $A$.
4. $A \subset B$ if and only if, for every $a \in A$, we also have $a \in B$. Is this true of the $A$ and $B$ you posted?

Comment: is it simply saying that if A = {x | x = R} and B = {A, {A}}, then, specifically saying, A is not a subset of B? Because set B does not specifically contain the elements of A, but only contains set A and set of set A?

Comment: Right. Suppose $A = \{0,2\}$ and $B = \{A, \{A\}\} = \{\{0,2\}, \{\{0,2\}\}$. 
Now, the elements of $A$ are $0$ and $2$. Are $0$ and $2$ elements of $B$?

Comment: I guess not, unless B is specifically written to be {0, 2, A, {A}}?

Comment: Exactly. Now you've got it!

Comment: Thanks! I feel safe finally