# If A is a set and B is = {A, {A}} why is A not a subset of B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I'm working through Discrete Mathematical Structures by Kolman, Busby, and Ross. In Chapter 1 I was given this example: "Let A be a set and let B = {A, {A}}. Then, since A and {A} are elements of B, we have A ∈ B and {A} ∈ B. It follows that {A} ⊆ B and {{A}} ⊆ B. However, it is not true that A ⊆ B." I understand that A is a subset of B only if all the elements present in A are present in B, but if B = {A, {A}} then why is A not a subset of B?

Comment: It is true indeed if $A=\varnothing.$ This is the only case if you assume regularity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity

Comment: The subsets of B are: $\emptyset, \{A\},\{\{A\}\},B$. But as Anne Bauval highlights, your example gives no information about the elements of A.

Comment: The example in the book just states that A is a set. It doesn't define what A is equal to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help on understanding a theorem on subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412008/need-help-on-understanding-a-theorem-on-subsets) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24B%3D%5C%7BA%2C%5C%7BA%5C%7D%5C%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24A%5Csubseteq%20B%24&p=1). Note your question is the proposed duplicate post's question #$4$. In addition, the same theorem is asked about in [Problem in understanding set theory](/q/50240), with a few parts of its answers also dealing with your question to some extent.

Comment: I think this post deserves both tags: elementary set theory and set theory, depending of the point of view of the asker and answerers.

Comment: Thanks @JohnOmielan! This looks like what I was looking for. I'll do my best to understand this.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Why did you close this question as a duplicate of a thread that gives the **WRONG answer**? Anne's answer here is the only correct one in both threads.

Comment: @user21820 First, note I didn't technically "close" this question. Instead, I only voted to close as a duplicate of another one. As for it being one where it gives the "**WRONG answer**", I agree it's not the best, but it being "wrong" is, I believe, debatable. Note the purpose of closing as a duplicate is where the question is answered in another one, even if the other question's answer(s) could be improved, including if the current question has a better answer (which I do agree with you re: Anne's answer). If you feel this shouldn't have been closed as that duplicate, please vote to reopen.

Comment: @JohnOmielan: Thanks for clarifying! I wish to also clarify that the consensus is not to close as duplicate unless the target thread actually has a mathematically correct answer. In this case, it's clear-cut that the answer there is wrong; the post itself is extremely misleading, and the comments under it make it clear that both the asker (hs2345) and answerer (Race Bannon) believe that A is not a subset of B, and that a simple example suffices (which wasn't even adequately justified). I will reopen-vote, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A\subseteq\{A,\{A\}\}$$
is true if $A=\varnothing.$

This is the only possibility if you assume the [regularity axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), because if $x\in A$ and $A\subseteq\{A,\{A\}\}$ then $A=x\in A$ or $\{A\}=x\in A$ but these two cases are forbidden by this axiom.

Note that on the other hand, $$A\in\{A,\{A\}\}$$ is always true. Beware of this distinction between $\subseteq$ and $\in.$

Comment: Can the downvoter please tell us how (s)he thinks I could still improve the answer?

Comment: I've only just recently started learning about sets and subsets, but from skimming through the article it does seem that the axiom of regularity would answer my question. I'll need to spend more time reviewing it in depth. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: @gumbojoe: The textbook that you cited is a terrible one. It is even more terrible that many university professors teaching discrete mathematics simply don't have the competency to realize this. Anne's (correct) answer uses the Regularity axiom from (ZFC) Set Theory not because it was the intended answer but because the textbook had the WRONG intended answer! Please chuck that textbook out of your (mental) reference shelf, because it is useless for real mathematics. I say this based on my decades of experience in teaching mathematics. Feel free to ask me further if you need clarification! =)

Comment: @user21820: Thanks for letting me know. Can you recommend any alternatives?

Comment: @gumbojoe: Unfortunately, I don't know of any discrete mathematics book that I can actually recommend. However, I do know that "How to Prove It" by Daniel Velleman is good (especially if you can get it cheap). It is not limited to discrete mathematics, but covers other topics at the lower undergraduate level. If you wish to chat with me further on mathematics or books, please request access to [this chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics) and ping me here again. =)