# terminology for subset of element of element of element... of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

**How to "search" for elements in a hierarchical structure of sets?**

In Naive Set Theory, by Halmos, for instance, the author describes many basic "data structures" such as ordered-pairs, but not more advanced ones, such as trees, that are so commonly used nowadays in computer science.  I'm wondering how to capture a binary decision tree, for instance, using standard sets, and then use an operator to "search" for an element in such a tree.

**More details:**

Let A be a set and let B = {A, {A}}. This is a tentative way to encode a tree with a root, labeled A, and a child, also labeled A.  Then, since A and {A} are elements of B, we have A ∈ B and {A} ∈ B. It follows that {A} ⊆ B and {{A}} ⊆ B. However, it is not necessarily true that A ⊆ B.

In this case: is there a terminology to denote the fact that all elements of set $A$ are elements of an element of an element of $B$?

Is there a terminology to denote the fact that set $A$ is a subset of an element of $B$?

More generally, is there a terminology to denote the fact that set $A$ is a subset of an element of an element of an element ... of $B$, where we use as many times the operation of taking elements of elements as needed?

I believe that this would be equivalent to searching for an element in a tree.

this is a follow up to [If A is a set and B is = {A, {A}} why is A not a subset of B?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778576/if-a-is-a-set-and-b-is-a-a-why-is-a-not-a-subset-of-b/4778582#4778582)

Comment: Being a subset of a subset is equivalent to being a subset, so any such terminology probably won't see much use.  Unless there is a specific reason to have the intermediate subset(s), they can be skipped.  Similarly, an element of a subset is also just an element of the set.

Comment: thanks, @abiessu I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: which false premise?

Comment: It seems you understood which one since you soon corrected it. But now  please focus one one question per post. Your recent edit (=first sentence and PS) and bounty should be a new post.

Comment: hi @AnneBauval to me all questions are related.  Let me try to fix it

Comment: There is a related concept in [Scott–Potter set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%E2%80%93Potter_set_theory#Preliminaries), that of *accumulation* (forgetting *urelements*): $\text {acc}(a) = \{ x \mid ∃b∈a (x∈b \text { or } x⊂b) \}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is notation expressing what you are describing.

Definiton: X = $\bigcup$Y = {z |∃b∈Y(z∈b)}

So the elements of X are the elements of elements of Y.

We define the following Recursive process:

$\bigcup^0$Y = Y

$\bigcup^{n+1}$Y = $\bigcup$$\bigcup^n$Y

This is allows us to consider increasing chains of elements of elements.... etc

If we want to discuss subsets of some element in $\bigcup^n$B, for some n

Consider the following:

Let A∈$\mathcal{P}(X)$ So that A is a subset of X

where X∈
$\bigcup\limits_{n∈ℕ} (\bigcup^{n}B$) = trcl(B) " Transitive Closure of B"

Note: We call $\bigcup\limits_{n∈ℕ} (\bigcup^{n}B$) the transitive closure of B because it is the smallest set containing B, that is transitive.

To sum everything up, to answer your question:

How can we refer to some set A, which is a subset of some element of element of element... n many times of B.

We say say that A is an element of the Powerset of some element in the Transitive Closure of B.

Comment: please, may you fix the post? many characters are not being correctly presented

Comment: I'll work on fixing the formating as soon as possible, sorry- my answer was typed off of my phone.

Comment: looking forward to your fixes